# Не срабатывает transition

Tags: html, css, css3

В этом случае цвет фона меняется плавно, а ширина - как если бы свойство `transition` не было бы задано, скачком.

Что здесь не так?

```
.h01 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFCC00;
    transition: width 3s;
    transition: background 3s;
}
.h01:hover {
    width: 200px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переходы нужно указывать через запятую.

```css
.h01 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFCC00;
  transition: width 3s, background 3s;
}

.h01:hover {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="h01"></div>
```

Также можно указать `transfition: all 3s;` - тогда анимированные переходы будут у всех свойств.

```css
.h01 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFCC00;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 3s;
  border: transparent solid 5px;
}

.h01:hover {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="h01">Текст</div>
```